# VARIANT returned by ActiveX using C# is NULL

Tags: c#-4.0, activex

Have source for ActiveX object written in C++ using VS2008. Have source for MFC main program written in C++ using VS2008 calling same ActiveX object. All works well. Now must create Windows Forms application written in C# using VS2010 that accesses same ActiveX object. With VS2010, click Tools, click Choose Toolbox Items, click COM Components tab, browse to ActiveX OCX file, click Open, import into COM Components list successfully. Create ActiveX object in derived Form class in C# source. Can successfully instantiate ActiveX object. Can successfully call CreateControl. Can successfully call several methods into ActiveX object. But having a problem calling methods in ActiveX object that return VARIANT. Upon addressing relevant method, C# indicates "object" is returned. Unfortunately, the "object" returned is NULL. How to resolve? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any response, after 19 views, except for one non-responsive negative vote without the courtesy of comment, the conclusion is that C# cannot process methods that return VARIANTs by value.